# abillity to select individual li with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of li which each include an menu options which slide out from the right, but I only want the click to apply on one li at a time.

```
$('#list li .swipe').click (function(i) {
        var t = $('.options');
        var ul = t.closest('#list');
        var selected = t.hasClass('selected');
        ul.find('li .options').removeClass('selected');

        if(!selected)
                t.addClass('selected');
 });

$('.options a').click(function(e) {
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("data-id");

      $(this).closest("li").fadeTo("fast", 0.01).slideUp("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
      e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Example of it in action
http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/V8Qvy/

Comment: _"I only want the click to apply on one li at a time."_ - Which one?

Comment: you can click on them in no particular order

Comment: I mean, how do you know which one the click should apply to? Or perhaps I mean that I have no idea what you mean. Can you please explain your requirement in more detail?

Comment: i just what the options from the right to be visible one at a time, current they all appear on one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly the following is all you need:

```
$('#list li .swipe').click (function(i) {
    $('.options').not( $(this).next().toggleClass('selected') )
                 .removeClass('selected');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V8Qvy/5/

Or if that looks to messy:

```
$('#list li .swipe').click (function(i) {
    var $current = $(this).next().toggleClass('selected');
    $('.options').not( $current ).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Or to allow for minor changes to html structure:

```
$('#list li .swipe').click (function(i) {
    var $current = $(this).closest('li')
                          .find('.options')
                          .toggleClass('selected');
    $('.options').not( $current ).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V8Qvy/6/

That is, start by selecting the clicked element with `$(this)`, and then navigate to the related `'.options'` div.

Comment: You're not unselecting the other rows when you select a row.

Comment: @Barmar - Good point. Overenthusiastic simplification on my part. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    var t = $(this).next('.options');
```

When you say `$('.options')` it matches all the options, not just the one after the DIV that was clicked on.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/V8Qvy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the class to the `this` element:

```
$('li .options').removeClass('selected'); // Clean the selected ones
if(!selected)
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // Apply to the clicked one
```

Comment: `selected` has to be added to the `.options` element, you're applying it to `.swipe` that was clicked on.